# Move eclipse tomcat project to standalone tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, deployment

i have done a project in eclipse,and i'm able to deploy and use the servlets from within the eclipse environment. my servlets are all functioning from 
 `http://localhost:8080/Report/ServletName`. I exported this project as a .WAR file. how do I deploy this WAR in a tomcat 6 setup on my ubuntu machine. and will the servlets still be available at the same address(`http://localhost:8080/Report/ServletName`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You drop the war file in the `webapps` folder of Tomcat. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html for documentation about deployment in tomcat. If the war file is named `Reports.war`, the web app will be available under the `/Report/` context path.

Answer (score 0):

All Tomcat deployment methods are explained in detail here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup .

I would recommend working with the Tomcat manager though.

The deployment address will change according to the name of your WAR file.